# How do I change the default on opportunity Notes and Attachments to be NOT private?

Tags: attachment, notes, checkbox, defaults, private

opportunity notes and attachments are always set to private by default but Users wanted it be made public by default.

Answer (score 0):

Notes and Attachments are a different in that their aren't permissions associated with them directly. Instead,  permissions are based on the parent object .

Instead of Notes & Attachment you use Chatter Files and upload your attachments to chatter files. 
Loading to Chatter files will let you take control on who can and cannot modify the attached file,